# how can get previously selected value in dropdown list in edit page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `viewbag` to put data in dropdownlist. In my edit page, I want to have selected value as the default value in my dropdown list.
I am sending dropdownlist from the controller class as follows:-

```
ViewBag.WareHouseId = new SelectList(db.WareHouse, "ID","Description");
```

my view code for dropdownlist is:-

```
@Html.DropDownList("WareHouseID","SELECT")
```

what should I add in the above line to show previously selected value before changing the value of drop downlist.?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the model value to the **optionLabel** parameter:

```
@Html.DropDownList("WareHouseID", "SELECT", Model.WareHouseID)
```